# Setting the charset of html response content to 1252

Tags: c#, character-encoding, httpresponse, windows-1252

I'm trying to send some data encoded in Windows 1252 (it's a CSV file) in an HTTP response, but somewhere along the way it's getting re-encoded to UTF-8 (no BOM). How can I make sure that the data stays in the correct encoding?

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
// Build the file from windows-1252 strings in the sb...
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("filename=\"{0}\".csv", fileName));
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv;charset=windows-1252";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "windows-1252";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Comment: how do you know that the reencoding takes place ? first make sure that the tools you are using to inspect the file/stream do not automatically perform some conversions. next try to deliver the file as an octet-stream (mime type `application/octet-stream`) and check the data received. In the code fragment you posted I suspect the `ToString` method called in  `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sb.ToString());` to supply utf-encoded data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(someString)
```

the input `someString` will be in .NET's internal string representation (actually UTF-16). To actually send the output this has to be converted. By default this conversion will be to UTF-8 (because it efficiently supports the whole of Unicode).

The `Charset` property simply sets the HTTP response headers. But not there is also a [`ContentEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contentencoding.aspx) property to actually control how strings are sent.

So you are missing

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")
```

See the description of [`System.Text.Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.Encoding.aspx) for a list of supported encodings.