# Serializing UTF-8

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am a bit newer to .NET.... I have searched for about 4 hours (perhaps not diligently enough), I will go ahead and ask anyway:

I have the following piece of code (I am using **Newtonsoft JSON.NET**) and it responds to my other API just fine (in JSON). The problem however is that in my model I am passing params that contain internationalized characters such as the following 'Ç'  :    these characters come out of the model fine (or at least, I think) but they get passed correctly. However when they get serialized into the output, they come out garbled like such (ex.):

```
'Ç' =>
A|™©

this.serializer.Serialize(context.HttpContext.Response.Output, this.Model);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is the output encoding declared? If it displays several chars instead of one international char, it seems you have to declare your output is not plain ASCII.

Comment: @YurySchkatula `public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
    if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
    context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.HttpContext.Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
    this.serializer.Serialize(context.HttpContext.Response.Output, this.Model);
    }` sorry i am not sure how to get thing formatted, but this is what I have so far

Comment: What is your browser-side encoding then?

Comment: I am using Unicode and I determined that the serializer is correctly generating the string/object but for some reason the Response stream is not sending it correct to the other API... or is it perhaps that the other API is not receiving it under the correct notion?

Comment: Seems that over API is ignoring the notion, because non-ASCII chars are encoded by several bytes in UTF-8.

Comment: I bumped your post as it's not clear to me how Newtonsoft encodes data during serialization.

Comment: @bvj my understanding is that it converts an object in it's hierarchical form to a JSON string

Answer (score 0):

After exploring this issue more I found the following to be a helpful answer arriving at a fix.

[Setting the charset of html response content to 1252](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266080/setting-the-charset-of-html-response-content-to-1252)

UPDATE 1/2/2015

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
context.HttpContext.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
this.serializer.Serialize(context.HttpContext.Response.Output, this.Model);
}
```

I had to set the coding on both sides (both API's) to UTF8